# Scripting actions by hand in Photoshop / Bridge

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-bridge, actions

Does anyone know if there's a less clunky way of creating actions than by using the built-in recording function in Photoshop? For instance, if I have an Action I want to alter slightly (add a step, alter a single step, etc.) it seems like I have to duplicate the action in the Actions menu, click down to where I want to alter the individual step, turn recording on, perform that step, stop recording, delete the old step, etc.

It would be a lot simpler if there was a simple scripting language that you could use to go in and alter an existing Action. I use expressions in AfterEffects and ActionScript in Flash so I know Adobe allows some scripting. Just wondering if anyone had an easier way to do this in Photoshop (I'll occasionally run Photoshop actions in Bridge if I need more pain / suffering in my life so I figured I'd ask about bridge, too).

Comment: On which platform are you using Photoshop? Knowing that will greatly affect the answers given to you on this topic.

Comment: Mostly MacOSX. I am looking for something to script within either Phtoshop or Bridge, which should be platform-independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, once an Action is made in Photoshop, it can't be changed later; a whole new one must be created from scratch. It's a real drag.

As an alternative, but for Mac OS X only, you should look into Automator, which offers up a lot of at least basic tasks that can be easily combined to make somewhat complex workflows.

Beyond that, you have to looking into [the scripting APIs](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html), which can be complicated to those who don't know how to program. The only cross-platform API for scripting the Adobe Creative Suite is Javascript. [Tutorials abound](http://www.google.com/search?q=Photoshop+javascript+tutorial) and any questions related to it should be directed to [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/photoshop+javascript). At the same time, once you wrap your head around using the scripting APIs in the language of your choosing, just about anything you can imagine is possible.

Comment: I've been able to edit sections of an action, but as I said it was clunky. I wasn't sure if there was a way to do this in bridge(hence the second tag) but I'll look into Automator. I've done a little Javascript hacking, so if it comes down to it i could probably look into that. Thanks!

Comment: Note that photoshop scripting is accessed via the file menu

Comment: @horatio: That's not entirely true. Javascripts are typically application specific, and I believe Visual Basic is as well. But on Mac OS X Applescript and Javascript (utilizing certain calls to the OS) can script Photoshop from outside the application itself.

Comment: I know, but it's a start. DDE etc was way beyond the intended scope of my comment.